# Binary search 2 ways to get mid

Tags: java, binary-search

What is the difference between

`int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;`

`int mid = (low + high) / 2;`

Which one is better?

Full code :

```
class Solution {
    public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
      int low = 0;
      int high = nums.length - 1; 
      while(low <= high)
       { 
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            if(nums[mid] == target)
                return mid;
            if(target > nums[mid])
                low = mid + 1;
            else
               high = mid - 1;  
      }       
        return -1;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit shift operators normally faster than arithmetic operators.

Comment: Maybe what you are trying to ask is what is faster, not better.

Answer (score 0):

`>>>` is unsigned right shift operator.

normally, `x >>> 1 == x / 2`, bitwise operator is much faster.

but, don't know Java will optimize if `x / 2` statement ?